# English-language term for "productive vasculitis"

Tags: terminology, pathophysiology

I'm translating a Russian text that gives a description of necropsy results. It mentions "productive vasculitis":

> Сосуды вокруг участка гранулематозного воспаления с признаками **продуктивного васкулита**.
>   Vessels surrounding the granulomatous inflammation site have signs of **productive vasculitis**.

Judging by the paucity of Google results for "productive vasculitis" (a mere 100 links), the phrase is a calque from Russian. I wonder how this type of vasculitis would be described in English.

Here's a [description of classification](http://www.wikiexclusive.com/medicine-and-drugs/vasculitis) I found online, written in English by a Russian specialist:

> Vasculitis (angiitis) is an inflammation of blood vessels (aortitis, arteritis, arterioles, capillaritis, phlebitis, lymphangitis). Vasculitis can be destructive (necrotic), **productive** and granulomatous.